# How to load an image on flutter using android studio

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a flutter app for the first time.  I figured out the initial error I was getting with yaml.  Now my error is "Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: assets/food.jpg.

Error building assets
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

I created a folder for the picture I am using named it 'assets' the pic is in the folder.  yaml is not recognizing the folder.  I guess the path is not correct.

flutter:

# The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

assets:
    - assets/food.jpg

The above code is what is on yaml.

Below is the code for android studio:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('EasyList'),
          ),
          body: Card(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset('assets/food.jpg'),
      Text('Food Paradise')
      ],),),

        ),
     );
  }
}
```

Below is the error:

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: assets/food.jpg.

Error building assets
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am trying to get the pic on to the app.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `pubspec.yaml` is properly indented & `food.jpg` image file is added in `assets` directory.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/food.jpg
```

Also make sure `assets` directory is created at root of project.

```
- app/
   - android/
   - assets/
   - lib/
   - pubspec.yaml
   - other directories/files
```

Comment: Rename `food (2).jpg` to `food.jpg` and move it inside `assets/` directory

Comment: Got it Thanks!  I suspected that I needed to remove (2) in the assets folder, but I wasn't sure.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score -1):

Below is how I have my 'assets' folder on flutter.  I have the assets folder open.  Is that correct?

```
flutter_practice
.idea
android
assets
food (2).jpg
gradle
ios
lib
test
.gitignore
.metadata
.packages
build.gradle
flutter_practice.iml
gradlew
gradlew.bat
local.properties
pubspec.lock
pubspec.yaml
README.md
```

Comment: Rename `food (2).jpg` to `food.jpg` and move it inside `assets/` directory. Instead of posting answer, you can edit your own post.